# Insert Data Into My DB trouble

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ado.net

This is the View code, this view will show a list of preInscription Demande and two button `Valide` and `Delete` the first one it allow `Webmaster` To `Inscription` and the seconde one to `Refuse` Demande.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<J2V.Models.preinscrit>>" %>
// some Html Code
<% foreach (var item in Model) { %>
            <li>
           <div class="listinfo">
                <h3>
                  <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nag) %>
                </h3>
                    <p>
                      <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Idag) %>

                    </p>
                    <span class="price"> <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Adrag) %> <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Vilag) %> <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Gov) %></span> <span class="media">Tel : <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Telag) %> |</span> <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Mailag) %>
                  </div>
                  <div class="listingbtns">
                    <span class="listbuttons"><%: Html.ActionLink("Valide", "Valide", new {mod= item}) %> |</span>
                    <span class="listbuttons"><%: Html.ActionLink("Supprime", "Delete", new { id=item.Idag }) %></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="clear">
                    &nbsp;
                  </div>
                </li>
    <% } %>
```

This is the "Valide" Action it allow To `Validate` preinscription and add Data to Agence Table and user table:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Valide(Models.preinscrit model )
{

        var db = new Models.J2VEntities();
        Models.agence ag = new Models.agence();
        Models.user user = new Models.user();
        ag.Adrag = model.Adrag ;
        ag.Gov = model.Gov ;
        ag.Idag = model.Idag;
        ag.Mailag = model.Mailag;
        ag.Nomag = model.Nag;
        ag.Vilag = model.Vilag;

        user.IsAdmin = false;
        user.iduser = model.Idag;
        user.password = Models.LogModel.register.CreateRandomPassword();

        db.AddTouser(user);
        db.AddToagence(ag);
        return View("index");
}
```

When I click on `Valide` on my view page I get this error :

> System.NullReferenceException

at this line `ag.Adrag = model.Adrag ;`

Comment: You must submit your form in view. Could you write full view code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no need to use form. use actionlink to send item.id.

```
<span class="listbuttons"><%: Html.ActionLink("Valide", "Valide", new {id= item.id}) %> |</span>
```

and get id in valide action and get the model in your database by item.id

```
public ActionResult Valide(int id )
{

    var db = new Models.J2VEntities();
    Models.agence ag = new Models.agence();
    Models.user user = new Models.user();

    //select from databese by id and valide

    ag.Adrag = model.Adrag ;
    ag.Gov = model.Gov ;
    ag.Idag = model.Idag;
    ag.Mailag = model.Mailag;
    ag.Nomag = model.Nag;
    ag.Vilag = model.Vilag;

    user.IsAdmin = false;
    user.iduser = model.Idag;
    user.password = Models.LogModel.register.CreateRandomPassword();

    db.AddTouser(user);
    db.AddToagence(ag);
    return View("index");
}
```

this code is from my project :

```
    //select list by id
    public IEnumerable<makale> select_makaleler_by_kategori(int kategori_id)
    {
        IEnumerable<makale> makale = (from m in entity.makale
                                      where m.kategori_id == kategori_id
                                      orderby m.olusturma_tarihi
                                      select m).ToList<makale>();

        return makale;
    }

    //select one element by id
    public makale select_makale(int makale_id)
    {
        makale makale = (from m in entity.makale
                         where m.makale_id == makale_id
                         select m).SingleOrDefault();

        return makale;
    }
```

Comment: I'i using Data Entity Framework So i'm wondring how to create search query ? some liink or exmple please.

Comment: I added an example from my project.

Comment: Sorry but i can't get the point until now, I'm beginner with ASP.net MVc and this is my first APP, So makale is your var but `entity.makale` what's it?

Comment: it is one of my database table

Comment: there is example about entity data model and linq here: http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/consuming-data-linq-to-ado-net-entity-data-model.html

Comment: This is my code :
    public Models.preinscrit select_makale(int id)
    {
        Models.preinscrit makale = (from m in Models.preinscrit
                         where m.Idag == id
                         select m).SingleOrDefault();

        return makale;
    }
Vs underline `Models.preinscrit`that After Form m in ... and show me the error No implementation found for this model.

Comment: I cant say more. Because I cant see your codes and entity model. this problem cant solve in this way.

Comment: First i have created My DB With Sql server Managment .
Seconde I created the EnTity Data Framework.
Is this right ? because I sow some exemple on net where user create The Model.cs class before DB and use Dbcontext

Comment: I know a have looot to learn, nothing gona stop me. I have checked my twitter ther's nothing :(.

Answer (score 0):

you are using ActionLink for the wrong reason , it isn't used for passing data , you should make a `<form>` and then submit it using `<input type='submit' />`

the problem happens because the 3rd parameter in the `ActionLink()` is the routing values that works with the routing rules , its not used for sending data

---

from the code sample i think the user didnt enter anything the view just for showing the page

if that is the case then just pass an id to the `ActionLink` and in the Controller action query again all the information from the database using the id

never depend on passing parameter used for showing purpose from page to page , a hacker can easily break your app

so if you dont want information from the user just pass the id then query again in the other page

Comment: And how to Do this ? where to put the `<form>`